# iOS Webview popups issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Am having a cordova cross platforms app which was working properly until release of iOS11.

Every popoup (ie. datepicker, combobox) in iOS11 Webview appears twice. So on 1 click is opened, closed and reopens again.

This has been reported as an iOS bug (https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=34492289).

Does anyone know any workaround?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: Yes. Apple have released a hotfix - dont know if the hotfix is fixing the bug as it doesnt say so allthough they said previously it will. Another solution has been implemented is our company is to change the webview. Works properly once done.

Comment: You have any link to the hotfix? What I already know is, the issue is not happening in the following cases ~ in iOS 11.2 ~ If changed to WKWebview from UIWebview ~ if build with xcode 8.3.3.  Is there any fix or work around to make it work in iOS 11.0 without the above cases ?

Comment: So Apple released a proper update of iOS system. Get update 11.2 and the problem disappears - no Webview change is required as well. If you want to  have this fixed without getting update the only option is the Webview change - this is what we've done as a B plan but thanfuly not needed.